# Phusion Passenger Error using .all function - is there a backwards compatible method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, passenger

I previously posted a question ([Performing multiple queries on the same model efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811712/performing-multiple-queries-on-the-same-model-efficiently)) which fellow StackExchange users kindly answered and saved me lots of processing time, avoiding lots of queries on my model by storing the results of a SQL query using the `.all` function

Specifically they advised `@chosenrecords = Everything.where('name LIKE ?', 'What I want').order('price ASC').all` be used

This appeared to work fantastically and I used it in a number of places in our code, however, having just uploaded it onto a live server I get an error message from Phusion Passenger for every line in which `.all` features.

The error is `syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting kEND .order('price ASC').all`

I have previously tried to gather information from the company hosting our sites regarding the versions of rails and passenger they're using, but without any success.  In the past anything that has worked locally has also worked on the server, provided I use `Ruby 1.9.3 i386-mingw32`.

Can anyone advise how I could fix this error?  Is there an older function that does the equivalent operation and may work on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that the old version of Passenger appears to be less robust to code falling across 2 lines, essentially I changed

```
@chosenrecords = Everything.where('name LIKE ?', 'What I want')
.order('price ASC').all
```

to the following and it works a dream

```
@chosenrecords = Everything.where('name LIKE ?', 'What I want').order('price ASC').all
```

Hopefully someone else will benefit from the errors of my ways!

Answer (score 0):

Actually that's not a Passenger problem, nor is it a matter of "less robust to code falling across 2 lines". The problem is this:

The first code exhibit is **illegal Ruby syntax**. If you to chain a to #order like that, you have to ensure that the first line ends with a dot. Otherwise Ruby will think that the first line is a single, complete statement, with the second one also being a single complete statement. Obviously a Ruby statement cannot begin with a dot, so in your first code exhibit, the second line raises a syntax error.